# How to delete a whole table in RealmBrowser?

Tags: react-native, realm

I have created some tables with Realm, and use Realm Browser for the visualization.I only can delete the contents in a table, but I could not delete a certain table, or insert data in a table. How can I fix this with this Realm Browser or any code?